# Response Cookie not getting set in CORS flask

Tags: python, flask, cors, setcookie, flask-cors

I am trying to set a cookie on a website a.com by making a fetch call from b.com

a.com is a flask application with below code

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS,logging
logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app,supports_credentials=True)

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"

@app.route('/setcookie', methods = ['GET'])
def setcookie():
  resp = make_response("Cookie Set")
  resp.set_cookie('userID', "test",max_age=60*60*24)
  return resp

@app.route('/getcookie')
def getcookie():
  name = request.cookies.get('userID')
  return '<h1>welcome '+name+'</h1>'

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

b.com is a simple web page with below code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
const url = "http://a.com:5000/";
fetch(`${url}setcookie`,{credentials: 'include'}).then(()=>{
    fetch(`${url}getcookie`,{credentials: 'include'});
})
</script>
Application page
</body>
</html>
```

When we load a.com it should ideally be able to get the cookie, this is working if they both are in the same domain.

Comment: The browser does not send or accept cookies crossing domains like that.

Comment: @KlausD. it does, you might have an application running on a domain in the cloud and a frontend running in your localhost, when you do login from localhost cookies are set in cloud domain in the browser.

Comment: Well, your observations tell otherwise. Which might be explained by the fact that the two scenarios you gave are two completely different things in the browser's security policies.

Comment: they are same b.com could be a webpage running on your localhost and a.com could be a backend running on cloud, I have another application where this is working just fine but that is a rails application.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started working after enabling third-party cookies in google chrome.